# A trick to find resultant pH

Tags: equilibrium, ph, ionic-compounds

Consider the following problem:

> Find the $\mathrm{pH}$ of the solution formed by the mixing of two solutions of $\mathrm{pH}$(s) $2$ and $3$ of equal volumes.

The normal way:

Since the resulting solution will have twice the volume, the new $\mathrm{pH}$ will be:
$$-\log\bigg(\frac{10^{-2}+10^{-3}}{2}\bigg)=-\log\bigg(0.0055\bigg)=\boxed{2.26}$$

Interestingly, my book mentions a trick:

> Find the average $\mathrm{pH}$ of the two solutions and subtract $0.24$ to get the actual $\mathrm{pH}$.

---

This trick surprisingly works for many problems with a remarkable accuracy. **I'm curious to find why this method works**.

Comment: Answered here in detail: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7051/why-does-this-shortcut-work-for-calculating-ph-proof-required

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto thank you. It solved my query. Unfortunately I was not able to find this question before.

Comment: The hidden part of this trick is that the volumes of solution A and B must be equal. Just be careful when you apply it.

Comment: The question, in the way it is formulated, has infinite number of possible solutions in near the whole pH range 2-3. I guess it implies, what should be stated explicitly, that both solutions are diluted strong acids.

Comment: This "trick" seems to me to be something that might be useful in a Chemistry Olympiad competition but useless in real laboratory work.

Comment: @MaxW of course. Students dont really get access to log tables in exams

Comment: @newbie105 - LOL, I did have log tables. When I started chemistry there were no such things as hand-held calculators. We used a sheet of log tables or in my case I was fortunate enough to have a Post Versalog sliderule in high school.

Comment: The "trick" is valid accidentally for particular pH difference equal to 1 for the same volumes of diluted strong acid solutions. It is mathematical consequence and has no direct relation to chemistry. It has no practical value.